# Understanding method returns

Tags: java

This is a working program, however I do not know what "return answer' accomplished here, only that something needs to be returned. Isn't there a way to use "answer" in the next method so number1-4 do not have to be retyped.

```
public class AverageOfGivenNumbers {

    // implement 
    public static int sum(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
         int answer = number1 + number2 + number3 +number4;
         return answer;
    }

    public static double average(int number1, int number2, int number3, int number4) {
        double average = sum(number1,number2,number3,number4) / 4.0;
        return average;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result = average(4, 3, 6, 1);
        System.out.println("Average: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the whole point of a return is so that you can use the function in other methods. Notice how `average` takes advantage of `sum` so you don't have to rewrite the code. Also, the main method could use `System.out.println("Average: " + average(4,3,6,1));` and do all that work in one tiny line of code. Return tells your code what `average(4,3,6,1);` will become. A call to that function will `return` a value, and the value in this case is the sum of the 4 numbers divided by 4 - `3.5`

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment or something, but if you were writing real code, you would probably pass `average` an array and count the number of elements so that it could give you the average of any set of numbers. In C# this is accomplished using `params int[] arguments`. You could then count the number of elements and divide by the count - I wouldn't write a `sum` function since that's pretty much built in functionality anyway, although you could write `sum` using `params` and accomplish the same kind of thing. It looks like it is just to demonstrate functionality in this case.

Comment: I would drop the whole word `number` and make it very short (like `n1`).
You can also drop the `int answer = n1 + ...` and just skip straight to `return n1+n2+n3+n4;`. With average, you could then write `return sum(n1,n2,n3,n4)/4.0;` which is quite short.

Comment: So  what does the line "return answer" do in this case?

Comment: it returns the sum of all 4 numbers passed , however you can reduce one line by directly returning the sum like return number1 + number2 + number3 +number4;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like homework, so it is likely just to demonstrate passing parameters.

As I said in my comments, you could shorten everything to this:

```
public class AverageOfGivenNumbers {
    public static int sum(int n1,int n2,int n3,int n4) {
         return n1+n2+n3+n4;
    }
    public static double average(int n1,int n2,int n3,int n4) {
        return sum(n1,n2,n3,n4)/4.0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Average: "+average(4,3,6,1));
    }
}
```

When we use `return`, we are saying what a function will evaluate to when we execute it.

This is shown in the main method where we use `average(4,3,6,1)`.

It becomes (or, "returns") `3.5` and that's what we see when we print it.

`Average: 3.5`

It doesn't show `Average: average(4,3,6,1)` because `average(4,3,6,1)` evaluates to `3.5` - the value we return.

Likewise, when we say `return sum(4,3,6,1)/4.0` - that becomes `return 14/4.0`.

You could also use this in java to pass unlimited arguments:

```
public static int sum(int... args) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int arg : args)
        sum += arg;
    return sum;
}
public static double average(int... args) {
     return (sum(args)/(float)args.length);
}
public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Average: "+average(4,3,6,1));
}
```

Comment: So the value returned in sum is used in the second method?

Comment: I see. So if that is true what are they doing in the parameter of average? Also, if I turn those into the variable "answer" like in my original code, where do they go? just trying to understand.

Comment: It's easiest to think of like this. Every method returns a value (except `void` methods). So when we say `public static double average` we are saying "This will turn into a `double` when we call it." We tell it what to turn into when we use the keyword `return`. You could just say `return 5` and it will always turn into 5 regardless of what you pass to it. All parameters you pass like this (until you get into more complicated references and pointers down the line) disappear (are garbage collected) when you leave the method (scope).

Comment: Also, even though the parameter names are the same in each method, they have nothing to do with each other. You could rename them to whatever they want and they only affect their own method. The best way to learn is to play with the code and see what happens. My #1 advice to you.

Comment: I guess the answer is it goes into that garbage collector. W/e I guess about the down votes, I asked a question, and it got answered. I guess they're down voting that lol. The exercise in the assignment wants me to use 2 methods, but this could all be down in one much better it seems.

Comment: they are downvoting you because posting working code here is not really the thing to do - supposed to post code you are struggling with (getting this compiler error - what am i doing wrong - stuck on this part - etc.) - there are codereview alternatives  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Glad you got it figured out though :) always happy to help aspiring programmers

Comment: Ya this site is very helpful for that sort of thing because of people like you helping us out. Helped me understand the return process.